# How to import a custom local version of a node module

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I'm currently developing a javascript project that has a [kepler.gl](https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl) dependency, but I need to edit the kepler.gl source code. 
I'm unable to import the modified version correctly.

Currently, it only works if kepler.gl is installed via npm/yarn and the import looks like this:

```
import KeplerGl from 'kepler.gl';
```

It's important to remember that kepler.gl folder has it's own node_modules directory.

My current directory structure:

```
MyApp
├── index.html
├── kepler.gl
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── src
├── webpack.config.js
└── yarn.lock
```

I've tried several ways, but I want to know the recommended way because I want a solution that will work with any configuration of babel, eslint, other packages installed, etc. that works with the original package.

Comment: You say "I've tried several ways", could you add details of what you've tried?

Comment: I've solved it. I'm posting the solution. But I could still add these details if it's important...

Comment: Still probably worthwhile, especially if your answer includes an explanation as to why previous solutions didn't work

Answer (score 0):

After some days of research I've found that the probably the recommended way is using link with yarn or npm:

The documentation is clear:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/